# Transforming two sets of test scores to be "comparable"?

Tags: data-transformation, standardization

Given 2 sets of test scores (the same students take both tests), I'd like to transform them such that they can be added to give a combined score.

The 2 tests have different variances, so adding them directly wouldn't work. Dividing each score by the standard deviation of that test then adding is better but this results in transformed tests that have different values for full marks. For example, if both tests were  out of 50, then after transformation one is out of 40 and the other out of 100, and this is found disconcerting as it doesn't feel like we're weighting the tests equally.

I'm wondering if there is a way to make both tests have the same variance while the score representing full marks is still equal in the two tests? For example, one way might be to convert both to percentiles and then add the percentiles, but I'm not sure if would be considered reasonable/acceptable practice, or if there is a better (e.g. nonlinear) way?

Comment: Why do you want them to have the same variances? What if the different variances reflect something about the tests?

Comment: I see your point, but the idea is that if one has a bigger variance, then directly adding the scores would give that test a bigger influence over the results, which we don't want. For example, if almost all scores for the first test are in a very small range but almost all scores for the second test are in a large range, then after adding test A would have almost no influence on the results. E.g. if test A and B test different competencies then we'd be valuing only one competency and ignoring the other.

Comment: Do test A and B test different competencies or the same ones? If the same ones, then the test with the small variance probably ought to contribute less.

Comment: They test different competencies, thanks for asking for clarification. Yup I agree that if they test the same things then the test with smaller variance should probably count less.